# Error: Could not locate a Flask application in VSCode

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

I am trying to learn `Flask` using VScode.

The tutorial that I am following is: [Python Flask Tutorial: Full-Featured Web App Part 1 - Getting Started](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwZwr5Tvyxo&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH).

I did the following things:

1. Created a new virtualenv in a folder using: `virtualenv venv`
2. activated it as: `venv\Scripts\activate` (I am on Windows 10)

After that, I created a new directory named `Flask_Blog` using `mkdir Flask_Blog` and in it, I created a new `flaskblog.py` file containing the following code:

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello'
```

Then, in the terminal of `VScode`, I changed my working directory in order to be in the `Flask_Blog` directory using `cd Flask_Blog`.

Now, when I am doing `set FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py` followed by `flask run`, I am getting the following error:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\kashy\OneDrive\Desktop\Flask\Flask_Blog> flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.
```

**But**

When I do the same in the `cmd` prompt, the code runs and I get to see the output.

I am completely new to this. Can anyone please tell me what is the mistake I am doing in `VSCode` and why is it working in the `cmd`?

Comment: I did do it. Since I am on windows, I did `set FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py` and the I did the `flask run`

Comment: I overlook that. comment deleted

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Issue raised in VsCode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/1881#issuecomment-425154463)

Under Powershell, you have to set the FLASK_APP environment variable as follows:

`$env:FLASK_APP = "webapp"`

Then you should be able to run "python -m flask run" inside the hello_app folder. In other words, PowerShell manages environment variables differently, so the standard command-line "set FLASK_APP=webapp" won't work.

Comment: $env:FLASK_APP = "webapp.py"

or for this current question,
$env:FLASK_APP = "flaskblog.py"

Answer (score 0):

Try Set FLASK_APP = Full path of the folder/filename.py.

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on the VSCode:

$env:FLASK_APP= 'C:\Python\ex003\main:app'

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the command explaining how it solves the problem.